# Is there another way to replace many times a specific element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I want to replace many times an element with an id like this :

```
$("#anIdElement").replacewith("#anotherIdElement");
```

This shouldn't work, so my question is : What can be used to replace many times a specific element with another another.

Example :

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td id="theFirsttd">Original content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="atd">Replace the current content by the original</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="atd">Replace the current content by the original</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

The problem here is that I can't replace the element with the id named atd, I can only once. Am I right ? 
So, is it possible to use something like `remove()` then `append()` to get it ?

Comment: The problem doesn't exist because ids have to be unique, hence there is always only one element with a specific id ;)

Comment: Yes I tried to clone but it didn't give me the same id and the cells are generated with an id

Comment: consider using `document.getElementByClassNames()` of javascript which will store the divs in an array.

Comment: Fix it at the source, ie. where the HTML is generated. Any attempt to fix this in JS is a hack and not addressing the underlying issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery you can do with these code, but first you must fix the html in your example:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td id="theFirsttd">Original content</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td class="atd">Replace the current content by the original</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td class="atd">Replace the current content by the original</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<script>
// reemplace all the items (jQuery)

$(function(){ // <- wait for the DOM
  var $first = $('#theFirsttd');
  $('.atd').each(function{ // <- eval each element with atd class selector
    $(this).replaceWith($first.clone()) // <- replace each one with first td clone
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You can put all id's you want to change in array and loop on it

```js
var array = ['theFirsttd', 'atd']

for (var item of array) {
 $(`#${item}`).attr("id", "newId");
}
```

watch out if you have same id name on severals elements (which is not supposed to happens as Id shoud be unique.

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, you're HTML is invalid because two objects share the same id - this could be solved by making those classes instead. Second, *assuming* that you are just copying the *content* of the one object to another object, using jQuery, you could do something like :

```js
$('.atd').html( $('#theFirsttd').html() );
```